# Error in mysql.h

Tags: mysql, c, gcc, cygwin, dev-c++

When I include mysql.h in my source file, I get all sorts of syntax errors. I'm using the cygwin gcc compiler and MysQL Windows Connector 6.0.2. I added an image of my IDE. What can I do to fix this? [Click here for larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOHw0.png)

[image]

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the errors here as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `winsock` right before mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Try including the header winsock.h before the mysql header.